# How to "merge" "duplicate" active record object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, google-maps-api-3

So, I'm building a map where i put pins (Google map).

I have a query that gives me position of my pins, however I can have multiple pins with the exact same position but a different description.

I've been banging my head against the desk on this since this morning for some reason I can't get a working solution,

Here is what I have so far:

```
building_permits = BuildingPermit.select('latitude, longitude, street, city, state, permit_number, description, type, id').where(:contractor_id => params[:nid])
@bp = Array.new
building_permits.each do |bp|
  @bp.push({"lat" => bp.latitude, "lng" => bp.longitude, "desc" => "<p><b>#{bp.street} #{bp.city}, #{bp.state}</b></p><p><b>Description:</b>#{bp.description}</p><p><b>Permit #{bp.permit_number}</b></p><p><b>#{bp.type}</b></p>", "id" => bp.id})
end
nb_rm = 0
building_permits.each_with_index do |bp, index|
  index1 = index
  building_permits.each_with_index do |bp2, index|
    if bp.longitude == bp2.longitude && bp.latitude == bp2.latitude && bp.id != bp2.id
      #debugger
      if @bp[index1].present?
        @bp[index1]["desc"] << "<br /><br /><b>Description:</b>#{bp2.description}</p><p><b>Permit #{bp2.permit_number}</b></p><p><b>#{bp2.type}</b></p>"
        @bp.delete_at(index-nb_rm)
        nb_rm += 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm sure there is something really stupid that's screwing the whole thing, but can't find it.

Comment: It would help if you could explain, in words, the merge rules you wish to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Try to duplicate your pin location:

```
# rails < 3.1
new_record = old_record.clone
#rails >= 3.1
new_record = old_record.dup
#and then
new_record.save
```

And after all change description of the pin.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and wanted to post my solution -- I had duplicate authors and wanted to find any authors where the name attribute was equal, and move related objects (books and recommendations) onto the first of each duplicate group, then delete the others.

```
Author.all.each do |a|
@name = a.name
if Author.where(:name => @name).count > 1
    first = Author.where(:name => @name).first
    a.books.each{|b| b.update_attributes(author_id: first.id)}
    a.recommendations.each{|r| r.update_attributes(author_id: first.id)}
end
end

Author.all.each do |a|
if a.books.count == 0 && a.recommendations.count == 0
    a.delete
end
end
```

Hopefully that can be helpful to someone!